# can i save data of an my app user in a file not data base

Tags: android, local-storage

I want save the user data on the device itself , but I don't want to use database.Can I do it? The app should use this data when ever it wants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use SharedPreferences:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Other storage options:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreferences is the best way for you to do that.